# jQuery: How to make function in an object public?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use a pagination plugin and I'd like to make one of it's functions public, so I can call it from "outside".  I can not call it directly, using `pageSelected($(obj))`.

Is there an easy way to make it visible so I can call it?

Jerry

Answer (score 1):

`window` is the global object in JavaScript, so do `window.myfunc = myfunc` and `myfunc` will be available globally.

Have a look at [line 818 of the jQuery core source](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L818) to see an example of this in action:

```
// Expose jQuery to the global object
window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a more Object-Oriented way to write plugins.

Hector Virgen posted a great approach on his blog:

http://www.virgentech.com/blog/2009/10/building-object-oriented-jquery-plugin.html

**Plugin code:**

```
(function($){

   var MyPlugin = function(element, options)
   {
       var elem = $(element);
       var obj = this;
       var settings = $.extend({
           param: 'defaultValue'
       }, options || {});

       // Public method - can be called from client code
       this.publicMethod = function()
       {
           console.log('public method called!');
       };

       // Private method - can only be called from within this object
       var privateMethod = function()
       {
           console.log('private method called!');
       };
   };

   $.fn.myplugin = function(options)
   {
       return this.each(function()
       {
           var element = $(this);

           // Return early if this element already has a plugin instance
           if (element.data('myplugin')) return;

           // pass options to plugin constructor
           var myplugin = new MyPlugin(this, options);

           // Store plugin object in this element's data
           element.data('myplugin', myplugin);
       });
   };

})(jQuery);
```

**Calling the plugin:**

```
$('#test').myplugin();
var myplugin = $('#test').data('myplugin');
myplugin.publicMethod(); // prints "publicMethod() called!" to console
```

Comment: Thank you. I've tried this also but it doesn't work for me (the approach). It says myplugin is not defined when I call the method ;-(

Comment: Dont forget to include the #test element somewhere in the body. Try this on a plain file, it should work:

http://pastie.org/1107876